Selecte Element in Shadcn-vue Selecte Component Type Proplem! in Nuxt.js
I have a problem attributing value from within the Select Component affiliate of Shadcn-Vue
in Nuxt.js
When I try to assign a value, I get this error

Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts-plugin(2322)
SelectRoot.d.ts(11, 5): The expected type comes from property 'modelValue' which is declared here on type 'Partial<{}> & Omit<{ readonly name?: string | undefined; readonly required?: boolean | undefined; readonly defaultOpen?: boolean | undefined; readonly open?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; "onUpdate:modelValue"?: ((value: string) => any) | undefined; } & ... 4 more ... & { ...; }, never> & Record<...>'

I used it this way.
<Select v-model="location.countryId">
                  <SelectTrigger class="w-[180px]">
                    <SelectValue />
                  </SelectTrigger>
                  <SelectContent>
                    <SelectGroup>
                      <SelectItem v-for="country in countries" :key="country.id" :value="country.id">
                        {{ country.name }}
                      </SelectItem>
                    </SelectGroup>
                  </SelectContent>                
</Select>

The value of location.countryId is supposed to be attributed to
const location = reactive({
countryId: 1,
cityId: 1,
regionId: 1,
> })

The value is supposed to go to
const countries = getCountries()
const cities = getCities(Number(location.countryId))

Note that I used
watch(
  () => location.countryId,
  (countryId) => getCities(countryId),
)

When you choose any value, the selection remains blank


Please [edit] your question title. You should always proofread what you've written before posting.

Why are you converting location.countryID into a Number? Does typescript know your countryID variable is an int?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48670111/typescript-type-number-is-not-assignable-to-type-string
